# Spin and parity of excited states and electron energy internal conversion

Tags: angular-momentum, nuclear-physics, conservation-laws, quantum-spin, parity

$^{95}_{41}$Nb $\beta^-$-decays to the first excited state of $^{95}_{42}$Mo. This state has an excitation energy of 768 keV and the de-excitation to the ground state goes via photon emission or internal conversion.

The spin and parity of  $^{95}_{41}$Nb and $^{95}_{42}$Mo can be determined from the odd proton/neutron to be $9/2^+$ and $5/2^+$ respectively (I used the energy levels from Shell model). How can I determine spin and parity of the excited state?

I also want to calculate the energy for the internal conversion electron. I suppose that it is not simply the excitation energy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computing the excitation spectrum for a nucleus — that is, its energy levels and their quantum numbers — is *hard*. Consider that the Schrödinger equation [has no known exact solutions for atoms other than hydrogen](http://www.nyu.edu/classes/tuckerman/adv.chem/lectures/lecture_9/node3.html): a helium atom, with three charges instead of two, is too complex to be treated except in approximation.  The nuclear many-body problem is much thornier.  Not only are there more participants in the system (ninety-five, for $^{95}$Nb), but in addition to the electrical interaction among the protons you have the pion-mediated attractive strong force, the rho- and omega-mediated hard-core repulsion, three-body forces, etc.  (I'm impressed that you got the correct spins and parities for the ground states from the shell model; nice work!)

So when normal people want to know the spin and parity and energy of a nuclear state, we look it up.  The best source is the [National Nuclear Data Center](http://www.nndc.bnl.gov/) hosted by Brookhaven National Lab, which maintains several different databases of nuclear data (each with its own steep learning curve).  Searching the [Evaluated Nuclear Structure Data File](http://www.nndc.bnl.gov/ensdf/) by decay for $^{95}$Nb brings up level schemes, with references and lots of ancillary data, for both niobium and molybdenum.  These confirm that you've gotten the $J^P$ for the ground states correct.  Two excited states are listed for $^{95}$Mo: one at $200\rm\, keV$ with $J^P = 3/2^+$, and the one you mention at $766\rm\,keV$ with $J^P=7/2^+$.  You can follow the references to see the experimental arguments for assigning those spins and parities.

You can make some general, hand-waving predictions about spins by thinking about angular momentum conservation in the transitions.
The matrix element for a particular transition is generally proportional to the overlap between the initial wavefunction and the final wavefunction.
In nuclear decays the initial state is the nucleus, which is tiny and more-or-less spherical with uniform density, while the final state includes the daughter nucleus and the wavefunctions for the decay products.  If the decay products carry orbital angular momentum $\ell$, the radial part of the wavefunction goes like $r^\ell$ near the origin.  Dimensional analysis then says that the overlap between the nucleus and the decay wavefunction is proportional to $(kR)^\ell$, where $R$ is the nuclear radius and $k = p/\hbar = 2\pi/\lambda$ is the wavenumber of the decay product.  (Note that nuclear decay products typically have $\lambda \gg R$, so you can treat the decay product wavefunction as roughly uniform averaged over the nucleus.)

If the probability of a decay is proportional to $(kR)^\ell$, that means that

- decays where the product's momentum $p=\hbar k$ is large are preferred over decays where the product's momentum is small
- decays where the orbital angular momentum $\ell$ is small are preferred over decays where $\ell$ is large

For your $\rm Nb\to Mo$ transition, the decay to the excited state is preferred over the $\frac92\to\frac52$ ground-state-to-ground-state transition, which suggests that the excited state probably has spin $\frac72,  \frac92, \frac{11}2$.  The most probable of these is $\frac72$, since angular momentum tends to relax during decay processes — and indeed, that's the spin of the $766\rm\,keV$ excited state.